# Git/Github misconfiguration makes push/pull take ages

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, push, pull

I have setup my git to use an SSH key. For a long time it has been working nicely, fast and no credentials asked every time I accessed the `origin`. All of a sudden, `push/pull` started taking ages.

Cause we have `git lfs` in use, sometimes I am checking out to a branch and it starts downloading some extra binary files. What is *most weird* about this, is that **each file** - no matter how small, *from a few bytes to 5MBs* - takes **half a minute** to download.

What is most annoying though is that *pushing to origin* also takes a long time: it takes **2 minutes** to actually start displaying any terminal messages, and after that it only takes 3-4 seconds to complete..!

Is there some kind of configuration I could change, or maybe a way to just reset everything to make it work?

Here is my `.git/config` file:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@github.com:xxxx/yyyy.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "bill/zzzzzzzzzzzzzz"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/bill/zzzzzzzzzzzzzz
[gui]
    wmstate = normal
    geometry = 1918x969+-10+45 825 578
```

plus 10-20 other `[branch "xxx"]` registrations below...

Answer (score 1):

Try ignore stat [1](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Diagnosing-why-Git-is-so-slow):

```
git config core.ignoreStat true
```

And try to enable filesystem cache [1](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Diagnosing-why-Git-is-so-slow):

```
git config core.fscache true
```

[Diagnosing why Git is so slow](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Diagnosing-why-Git-is-so-slow)

Comment: Thanks but the problem of taking forever to download each *lfs* file persists. I'll try that Github link. *EDIT*: just saw that this page is for Windows users. I am using *Ubuntu* and I'd *want* it to run as fast as on Windows :-(